# Using git archive as npm dependency

Tags: git, node.js, npm

With npm you can declare a dependency with a URL that points to a gzipped tarball containing a node module. I got this working by running the tar command in OSX terminal. But I'd rather use git archive so that the output doesn't include the .git stuff and things ignored by the repo (node_modules).

I create the archive like so:

> git archive master | gzip > ../archive.tar.gz

But then when I try to install it with npm (npm install archive.tar.gz or put it in package.json) it fails with this error:

```
npm ERR! couldn't unpack /var/folders/gc/6rgb6g4x0n96nc1scbvv87040000gn/T/npm-1329949280846/1329949280846-0.19062370574101806/tmp.tgz to /var/folders/gc/6rgb6g4x0n96nc1scbvv87040000gn/T/npm-1329949280846/1329949280846-0.19062370574101806
npm ERR! Could not install: /javascript/archive.tar.gz
npm ERR! Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory '/var/folders/gc/6rgb6g4x0n96nc1scbvv87040000gn/T/npm-1329949280846/1329949280846-0.19062370574101806/package/package.json'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "/javascript/archive.tar.gz"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/dave
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-10
npm ERR! path /var/folders/gc/6rgb6g4x0n96nc1scbvv87040000gn/T/npm-1329949280846/1329949280846-0.19062370574101806/package/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! message ENOTDIR, not a directory '/var/folders/gc/6rgb6g4x0n96nc1scbvv87040000gn/T/npm-1329949280846/1329949280846-0.19062370574101806/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dave/npm-debug.log
```

Any idea what would be different between the git archive and a regular tar, that would cause npm install to fail?

Comment: You omitted the `--format=tar` option to `git archive`; is it possible it created a zip?

Comment: tar is the default, but yeah I tried the explicit --format=tar, same effect. Good suggestion to try though.

Answer (score 0):

While the format of the archive could have a role in this issue (as [Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383402/borealid) mentions in the comment), I would also double check if this isn't related to a length issue in the parameters `npm` has to deal with.
See this [issue on npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1488) 5 months ago, with this [fix proposed](https://github.com/cspotcode/npm/commit/79345535edb08e5a9a486e07b11dd4dcacff32a0) (that was for Windows, but could still have an impact in your environment, if the path is *really* long).

See also [issue 1951: "Can't unpack with tar (on Mac)"](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1951), where the version of `tar` was not compatible with `npm` (as in [issue 1511](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1511) as well, also on Mac).

Comment: could be something along those lines. I'll post it on the npm site and see if it is indeed an npm bug. Thanks for the help.